# WebViewAdd Custom Menu Item in Contextual Action Bar with overriding existing

Tags: android, android-webview, contextual-action-bar, actionmode

I need to add some custom menu items in contextual action bar for WebView. My current research shows that only one of the following two things can be done.

1. Override action mode to supply custom action items. In this case default items are gone.
2. Use system provided action mode. In this way, I can't add my menu items.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May this will solve your problem.
https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android